# making a pdf report application from blank form using scriptcase

Tags: php, pdf, report

Does anyone here know how to create a pdf report application from blank form using scriptcase?
i've been using scriptcase for quite a while now and the pdf report application doesn't give as many actions and event that i need to do. so i've decided to try to create a pdf report application from blank form. The problem is i dont know how to do it. but it is possible right?

Comment: scriptcase? try to look up fpdf in case you don't know it yet.

Comment: @albertdiones i try looking at fdpf. and whats bothering me now is all the other classes i have to include in the library to make it running. Like the fpdf itself. I want to learn how to construct it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with a library like FPDF or mPDF.

Comment: You should specify an example or use case that supports your answer.